# What could disable terminal ANSI color code?

Tags: windows, terminal

I've written a code (`moz-can-run-script-boundary-adder/index.js` here) that consumes `stdin` and emits it with gray color (using [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk), `` console.log(chalk`{gray ${line}}`) ``). For first few lines it properly emits gray lines, and then suddenly it starts emitting bare color codes.

(Consider `./mach build` here as a black box)

```
> ./mach build | node ../moz-can-run-script-boundary-adder/index.js
MozillaBuild Install Directory: C:\mozilla-build\
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
unable to start ssh-agent service, error :1058
Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory
←[90m 0:00.91 Clobber not needed.←[39m
←[90m 0:01.24 Adding make options from C:\Users\Kagami\Documents\GitHub\gecko-dev\mozconfig←[39m
←[90m    AUTOCLOBBER=1←[39m
←[90m    MOZ_OBJDIR=C:/Users/Kagami/Documents/GitHub/gecko-dev/obj-x86_64-pc-mingw32←[39m
←[90m    OBJDIR=C:/Users/Kagami/Documents/GitHub/gecko-dev/obj-x86_64-pc-mingw32←[39m
←[90m    FOUND_MOZCONFIG=C:/Users/Kagami/Documents/GitHub/gecko-dev/mozconfig←[39m
```

This happens on PowerShell 7.1.1 and Windows Terminal app.

What could possibly cause this? Is there a specific ANSI escape code that disables any following codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was [SetConsoleMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode). [Per the bugzilla comment](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1417003#c13), [MSYS somehow sets the flags as `ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT | ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT`](https://github.com/msysgit/msys/blob/96f67347bc237ca689ad6f13e634d49f9de38cab/winsup/cygwin/fhandler_console.cc#L736) without `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` and that caused this issue.